# Django App name 'tests' conflicting with some built-in name

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have an App in my Django project called tests.

When I try to import models from this app into another app-

```
# regression/views.py

from tests.models import TestCases
```

Django gives error:

```
    from tests.models import TestCases
ImportError: No module named models
```

But there is models.py in **tests** folder.

This is happening with only 'tests' app as I am able to import successfully from all other Apps. I think it is because 'tests' might be some internal built-in name.

How to handle this conflict?

Comment: If you can't change the app name, you can try a relative import, eg `from .tests.models import TestCases`.

Comment: Did you try to import the model on project scope? `from project.tests.models import TestCases`

Comment: Open the Python interpeter in your project folder and run `import tests` then just `tests` to see what clashes.